# Mass Assignment warning when using association methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very odd mass assignment error that shows up when I use association methods to create new objects.

I have a user model that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

I also have a posts model that looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :body, :title
end
```

If I do the following in console, I get a mass assignment warning:

```
> user = User.create(:name => "Daniel");
> user.posts.create(:title => "Hello World")
=> #<Post id: 1, body: nil, title: "Hello World", created_at: "2011-11-03 
   18:24:06", updated_at "2011-11-03 18:24:06", user_id = 1>
> user.posts
=> WARNING: Can't mass-assign attributes: created_at, updated_at, user_id
```

When I run `user.posts` again, however, I get:

```
> user.posts
=> [#<Post id: 1, body: nil, title: "Hello World", created_at: "2011-11-03 
   18:24:06", updated_at "2011-11-03 18:24:06", user_id = 1>]
```

There are a couple of other tricks I can do to avoid the mass assignment error, such as calling `user.posts` before I do `users.posts.create`.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

I'm using Rails 3.0.7.

Comment: Upgrading to Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.2 still hasn't solved this problem.

It's not much of an issue, since it only prints a warning, but it makes it impossible to raise an error in development when that warning is generated.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your user model to include attr_accessible for posts association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :posts
end
```